# Execute the code inside a range slider watcher only after I have selected range and not constantly as I slide the slider?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I made a function which watches for changes on the range property and executes a new GET request in order to get all sights in that new range. Unfortunately, I keep getting `Too many requests` error from the API. I assume this is because the functions gets executed literally on every `range` property change which is gonna be often while I'm sliding the slider.

This is why I'm wondering what can I do to only execute the function once after I have finished sliding the sliding bar of the range slider?

HTML

```
<input v-model="range" class='range-input' type="range" min="1000" max="25000" value="10000">
```

JS

```
data(){
    return {
        sights: [],
        username: this.$route.params.username,
        city: this.$route.params.city,
        lat: this.$route.params.lat,
        lng: this.$route.params.lng,
        type: 'museum',
        range: 5000,
    }
},
watch: {
    range: function(){
        axios.get('/getSights/' + this.lat + '/' + this.lng + '/' + this.type + '/' + this.range)
        .then(response => {
            this.sights = response.data.result.results
            this.nextPageToken = response.data.result.next_page_token
            console.log(response)
        }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, you should remove the value attribute in your html if you already use `v-model` to bind it to a property. If you need a default value, set the property in js to that value, but don't interact with the html-element's value yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen to the change event to actually do the request.

```
<input @change="doRequest" v-model="range" class='range-input' type="range" min="1000" max="25000" value="10000">
```

Comment: Or `<input @change="range = $event.target.value" :value="range" class='range-input' type="range" min="1000" max="25000" value="10000">`. to avoid the creation of `doRequest` method.